# Python display the data array by left shifting the string data

Tags: python

I want the display the array data by left shifting the `str` data. I have wrote the code, its working partial. The code is as below:

Is it possible in Python,what I am expecting as Output.Provide the solution

```
response = '62 D9 57 00 00 25 27 00 00 28 77 00 02 4D 27 11 22 33 44'
data = response.split()

index = 3

for i in range(0,3):
    TempMSBData = (data[index])
    print '1st Byte:' + ' ' + TempMSBData
    index = index + 1
    MSBData = (data[index])
    print '2nd Byte:' + ' ' + MSBData
    index = index + 1
    TempLSBData = (data[index])
    print '3rd Byte:' + ' '+ TempLSBData
    index = index + 1
    LSBData = (data[index])
    print '4th Byte:' + ' ' +LSBData
    index = index + 1
    DataResponse =(( int(TempMSBData) << 24)|( int(MSBData) << 16) | ( int(TempLSBData) <<8)| int(LSBData))
    print 'Data_Ary_[{}] = {}'.format(i, DataResponse)
```

I am getting the Output as below with `Error`

```
1st Byte: 00
2nd Byte: 00
3rd Byte: 25
4th Byte: 27
Data_Ary_[0] = 6427
1st Byte: 00
2nd Byte: 00
3rd Byte: 28
4th Byte: 77
Data_Ary_[1] = 7245
1st Byte: 00
2nd Byte: 02
3rd Byte: 4D
4th Byte: 27

Error is : DataResponse =(( int(TempMSBData) << 24)|( int(MSBData) << 16) | ( int(TempLSBData) <<8)| int(LSBData))
           ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4D'
```

I am expecting the output as below:

```
1st Byte: 00
2nd Byte: 00
3rd Byte: 25
4th Byte: 27
Data_Ary_[0] = 2527
1st Byte: 00
2nd Byte: 00
3rd Byte: 28
4th Byte: 77
Data_Ary_[1] = 2877
1st Byte: 00
2nd Byte: 02
3rd Byte: 4D
4th Byte: 27
Data_Ary_[2] = 024D27
1st Byte: 11
2nd Byte: 22
3rd Byte: 33
4th Byte: 44
Data_Ary_[3] = 11223344
```

Comment: Those are hexadecimal values. You'll need to provide base 16 to the int function when converting it to an int.

Comment: I tried doing that, error will go, but what about my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to take a long string of hex parts and chunk them up into groups of 4 and want to print the hex value.

You can take a common python idiom to chunk up the `split()` using `zip()`:

```
for x in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
```

`x` will iterate over the data in chunks of 4, e.g. first time around the loop `x = ('00', '00', '25', '27')`. You could unpack to your variables (but I am not sure that helps):

```
for TempMSBData, MSBData, TempLSBData, LSBData in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
```

If you don't need the numerical value you can do this all in strings and just `lstrip()` off the `0`s:

```
In [1]
response = '62 D9 57 00 00 25 27 00 00 28 77 00 02 4D 27 11 22 33 44'
data = response.split()[3:]
for x in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    print(''.join(x).lstrip('0'))

Out[1]:
2527
2877
24D27
11223344
```

However, if you want it numerical then you can simply `join` the parts and convert to `int(n, 16)` base 16. However, when you print it out you need to `format()` to a hex `x`:

```
In [2]:
for x in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    print(format(int(''.join(x), 16), 'x'))

Out[2]:
2527
2877
24d27
11223344
```

You are getting the values you see because you are printing in decimal:

```
In [3]:
for x in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    print(format(int(''.join(x), 16), 'd'))

Out[3]:
9511
10359
150823
287454020
```

However, your calculation isn't right, you need `int(x, 16)`.

To do it all numerically you can do:

```
In [4]:
for x in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    i = 0
    for n in x:
        i <<= 8
        i |= int(n, 16)
    print(format(i, 'x'))

Out[4]:
2527
2877
24d27
11223344
```

Comment: Super explained.If i want as Data_Ary_[0] = 2527, Data_Ary_[1] = 2877, what need to change in code

Comment: Create the array `Data_Ary_ = []` outside of the loop and `Data_Ary_.append(i)` inside the loop - or look into `list comprehensions`